# How to install a Credential Provider in Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-c++, dll, installation, windows-8.1, credential-providers

I am currently trying to implement a custom credential provider on Windows 8.1 and have been looking at various blogs, articles and the samples from the Windows 8.1 SDK.

The implementation of the credential provider is okay and I believe I have a grasp of the concept required to implement the custom provider.

However, the issue I have is that I am unsure how to "install" the credential provider itself. The sample provided in the Windows 8.1 SDK compiles a .dll. This DLL does not register with REGSVR32, so I am unsure how to make the system aware of this provider.

Does anyone know how I install the credential provider? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you need to add it to the registry: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the GUID of the DLL to the Credential Providers list, however because the DLL isn't registered (I suppose you would call it), then the GUID means nothing because LogonUI doesn't know what that GUID belongs to?

Comment: A credential provider is a COM interface, so presumably it just needs to be registered with COM.  But I'm not familiar with the sample code in question so I'm not sure how you're supposed to do that.  What happens when you try `regsvr32` ?

Comment: When trying to register using regsvr32, an error is displayed saying the the DllRegisterServer entry point is not found in this module.

I found a couple of resources on the web that say that I need to copy the DLL to the C:\Windows\System32 and add a couple of registry entries to the Credential Provider key in HKLM. I've done this, but after reboot, I cannot see any additional credential provider on the logon sceeen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install a credential provider, you have to follow two easy steps :

- copy your DLL in the System32 folder (located in C:\Windows\System32).
- create some keys in the registry. If you used the sample from microsoft, you should have a register.reg file included. You just have to execute it, and the right keys will be written.

If you want to unregister your credential provider, just run the "unregister.reg" file.

There is now a [proper documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53556) for credential providers, which anyone who wants to work with them should read.

Comment: There are exist documentation for `Windows 10` - [Credential Provider Technical Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53556)

Answer (score 3):

**RegisterCP.reg**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential
>   Providers\{GUID}] @="CP_Name"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}] @="CP_Name"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}\InprocServer32] @="CP_Name.dll"
>   "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

**UnregisterCP.reg**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential
>   Providers\{GUID}]

Comment: Pease fix registry paths - missed second backslash symbol (must be double before {GUID}) to be correctly displayed,

Comment: @Alexander- Thanks mate